# Where is the default configuration for Project "Output Directory" & "Intermediate Directory" saved?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

I seek to change the following default configurations for new Visual C++ Projects in VS 2008

1. Output Directory        [ currently: $(SolutionDir)$(ConfigurationName) ]
2. Intermediate Directory  [ currently: $(ConfigurationName) ]

The default template project does not contain this setting. And I am unable to find any related file (.props or .vsprops). I believe it could be connected to avialable platforms [Win32|x64].

Note that I need a solution that points to and changes the configuration in place and Not in an external template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was connected to available Platforms indeed. The installed platforms located at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\VC\VC_OBJECTS_PLATFORM_INFO{Platform-Identifier} : CLSID points to a DLL like %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\ **VCProjectEngine.dll**. This is the "Project Configuration Provider". It implements various components of the interface. e.g. 'get_DisplayName' to show the Congiuration Name in the GUI.

The default configurations like 'Output Directory' and 'Input Directory' are **Hard Coded** in this binary file.